# Adding and Multiplying Radio button values with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, addition, multiplication

I have a survey form I developed and placed in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tMUJT/

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){ 
  var tot=0;
  $('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
    tot+=parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  tot+=parseInt($('#more').val());
    $('#usertotal').html(tot)
  });

  $('#more').change(function(){
    $('input:radio').trigger('change');
});
```

Each radio input has the value of 1.

I need to show the sum of each column beneath each column and then show a final sum based on the calculation below:

column1 total x 0 + column2 total x 1 + column3 total x 2 + column4 total x 3 + column5 total x 4 =

I tried re-purposing many scripts but just couldn't get it to work - my js skills aren't that great. If some could please help me make it work in jsfiddle, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3qh8D/1/

I like to use [html5 data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) for this sort of thing. You can call it what you'd like but I used `data-factor` (actually `weight` would make more sense). I think it's better to put this into markup. That way when you generate the markup you can bind the value that you're looking for directly into the HTML rather than having some sort of mapping in your code somewhere that says "this css class is equal to 1 and this css class is equal to 2" etc.

```
<td bgcolor="#00CC66"><input type="radio" data-factor='1' name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1"></td>
<td>On shelf</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFF33"><input type="radio" data-factor='2' name="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="1"></td>
<td>No</td>
<td bgcolor="#fba459"><input type="radio" data-factor='3' name="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="1"></td>
<td class="dots">&nbsp;</td>
```

Then whenever one of the radio buttons changes you just roll through all the checked inputs and add up the `data-factor` values.

```
// column1 total x 0 + column2 total x 1 + column3 total x 2 + column4 total x 3 + column5 total x 4 =

$(':input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  var $inp, factor, inp, inputs, total, _i, _len;
  total = 0;
  inputs = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
  for (_i = 0, _len = inputs.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    inp = inputs[_i];
    $inp = $(inp);
    factor = $inp.attr('data-factor') || 0;
    total += +factor;
  }
  return $('#totalValue').text("Total value:" + total);
});
```

(the fiddle is in coffeescript because I find that more readable)

Comment: Everytime I click a radio button in that fiddle im getting a lot of undefineds in the totalValue div

Comment: yea it works now. Way more efficient than my solution... I have no idea how you did it

Comment: @Kierchon thanks man; feel free to ask a question about it, I'll try and help

Comment: I kind of get it now. Ive just never seen data-factors or used them before so I didnt get how you could just loop through them all like that but I understand now. Good solution

Comment: Can you explain `factor = $inp.attr('data-factor') || 0;` whats the `|| 0` for?? Also `total += +factor;` What is the + infront of factor for?

Comment: well it can be `data-anything` so if we just wanted `data-n` that would work.

Comment: `factor = $inp.attr('data-factor') || 0` means if you get null or undef in the first you just fall through to the second -- that way you'll never add null to your numbers

Comment: `total += +factor` the + coerces the returned value (a string) to be a number. try `0 + +'A'` vs `0 + +'1'` and you'll see it

Comment: Awesome JC! Thanks so much! Extreme newb question...coffescript? Do I need to do anything special to facilitate coffescript?

Comment: Not much. Hit up http://coffeescript.org/ and read about it. I prefer it. If you've ever written Ruby you'll love coffee. However: it's important to be able to flip between coffee and javascript. I just find coffee to be faster to write. Also, I use grunt to automatically compile my coffeescript to javascript but the coffee command line can do that for you too. Grunt offers more options.

Comment: Got it to work. However, I discovered a computational error. Assuming you could see the sum and the end of each column, If you were to select all radio buttons in each column, col1 would be 3, col2 col3 and col4 would be 14 and col5 would be 5. Note in the original jsfiddle, some rows don't offer an option(ommitting the button). 

As is, on rows with no yes yes yes no I 
applied data-factor='2' data-factor='3' data-factor='4'

Comment: ...if that doesn't make sense, please let me know

Comment: Sorry... nevermind...I'm an idiot - I was starting with 1 instead of 0. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem man, I thought you'd be able to get it on your own.